# TSQL : Removing Square Brackets from JSON child property

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017, for-json

I have the following SQL query to create JSON. I using `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` so the root does not create array.

```
select *
from Documents D
join Notices Notice ON Notice.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
join NoticeDetails NoticeDetail on NoticeDetail.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
where d.DocumentID = 1234
FOR JSON Auto,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

The above query produce the following JSON. ( For brevity purpose i have removed some json properties)

```
{
    "DocumentID": 1234,
    "ClientID": 3,  
    "Notice": [
        {
            "DocumentID": 1234,
            "StateCode": null,          
            "NoticeDetail": [
                {
                    "NoticeDetailID": 80122,
                    "DocumentID": 1234,                             
                    "CreatedDateTime": "2020-03-26T16:08:40.730",
                    "ModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-26T16:08:40.730"               
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`DocumentID` is PK in `Documents` table and FK in `Notices` and `NoticeDetails` table. Also its UNIQUE KEY in `Notices` table.
So basically `Documents` to `Notices` is 1 to 1 relationship. So i do not want `Notice` property to be an array in output json.

My expected output json should be

```
{
    "DocumentID": 1234,
    "ClientID": 3,  
    "Notice": 
        {
            "DocumentID": 1234,
            "StateCode": null,          
            "NoticeDetail": [
                {
                    "NoticeDetailID": 80122,
                    "DocumentID": 1234,                                         
                    "CreatedDateTime": "2020-03-26T16:08:40.730",
                    "ModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-26T16:08:40.730"               
                }
            ]
        }       
}
```

What should be my SQL to get expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple SELECT statements into a single JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552806/multiple-select-statements-into-a-single-json) And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58638141/3094533) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53563039/3094533).

Answer (score 0):

I think i found it. Based on [SO POST here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563039/how-to-remove-the-square-brackets-in-child-rows-of-a-json-from-sql-server-2016)

```
select *,
JSON_QUERY((
    SELECT *
    ,JSON_QUERY((
        SELECT * FROM NoticeDetails NoticeDetail
        WHERE NoticeDetail.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
        FOR JSON PATH
    )) AS NoticeDetail
    FROM Notices Notice
    WHERE Notice.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
    FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)) AS NOTICE
from Documents D
where d.DocumentID = 1234
FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Comment: With over 15K reputation, you should know by now that this question is a duplicate and should be closed as such, not post an answer to it.

Comment: why does it matter. Does SO is lack of space? sometime SO search does not return what exactly what you are looking for. Also i found my own answer before you post.

Comment: Yeah, you've found your answer in another post... It doesn't matter that much, that's just the way this website is supposed to work....